# Where does code to run complex algo for android mobile app runs?

Tags: android, amazon-web-services

I have a table (PostpaidCustomers) of mobile numbers and corresponding names in a AWS table.

It contains near about 1 million items. I want to fetch those mobile numbers and customer names having 4 zeroes together in their mobile number. How can I calculate this?

Shall I leave this to AWS query or can I compute this in my java android code?
If I compute this in my java android code, where this code will run? Do I need to use Amazon Compute Engine for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A common pattern we have seen is for people of offload this type of expensive computation from the device to a system in the cloud, like AWS Lamdba, and access the results of the computation through an API interface. Using Amazon EC2 is another popular option, however AWS Lambda is more convenient from a deployment/management complexity point of view.